# Angular.js + ui-router wrong controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I'm using angular 1.6.1 and angular-ui-router 0.3.2.

I have basic routes set-up as follow:

```
{
  state: 'home',
  config: {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '...',
    title: 'home'
  }
},
{
  state: 'view',
  config: {
    url: '/view',
    controller: '...',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: '...',
    title: 'view'
  }
}
```

this object then gets passed as needed to `$routeProvider.state()`.
in my `home` state I use `$state.go()` to switch to the `view` state.
When I'm at the view state my template looks like so:

```
<div>
  <div class="go-back" ng-click="vm.goBack()">
    <img src="/src/assets/images/back.png"/>
  </div>
  <tabs>
    <tab>
      <directive1></directive1>
    </tab>
    <tab>
    </tab>
    <tab>
    </tab>
  </tabs>
  <directive2></directive2>
  <directive3></directive3>
</div>
```

Each directive here has a bound controller to it.

My problem is that the directives controller are wrong. What I mean by it is if I inspect for example `directive2` html in the inspector, and try to inspect it's controller in chrome using `angular.element($0).scope()` I will get a scope which is not the correct scope of the directive.
Even weirder it's parent scope is the scope of `directive3`. If I were to remove `directive3` from the template than `directive2` will start working again, and it will have the correct scope attached to it.
If I were to place `directive2` under `directive3` in the template it will solve this problem as well.
Same problem for the `<div class="go-back">...</div>` element inside the template. It's scope is the correct one and the `vm.goBack()` function is called, but if I were to remove `directive3` from the template then `vm.goBack()` won't be called anymore (even tho when inspecting the element scope in the console, it is the correct scope).
Problem remains for other controller to, not having their correct scope attached to them for some reason and I can't figure out why.

Comment: ui-router uses `$stateProvider` to configure states and the `config` property seems strange. Create a plunker that reproduces issue

Comment: @charlietfl when I said I pass it as needed, I meant that I iterate over this array of object and I pass it like so `$routeProvider.state(obj.state, obj.config)`

Comment: but should be using `$stateProvider`. Create a demo

Comment: @charlietfl well I tried to make it a simplified version of the problem but I couldn't test it, it seems as `app.js` in my pluncker won't load, could you take a look ? https://plnkr.co/edit/XZ9LKbO8JCFwcNGR92qW

Comment: @Jorayen if you don't mind, I took a look at your plunkr and fixed it up. Perhaps you can continue with the example of your problem? https://plnkr.co/edit/31eEdliEZle7ckpqWTqo?p=preview

Comment: @AHAY I've updated my plunker go check it out. I think I understand my problem better. I need to use ui-router `views` I guess, that's what making my different directives behave incorrectly. Although I can't still get it right in my plunker, mind telling me what have I done wrong ?

Comment: @Jorayen not sure if this is what you were trying to do, but your controllers show up now: https://plnkr.co/edit/o5zEyhp3ppbFZZtc4oM9?p=preview. in order to use ui-router's views object, you have to set the name in a tag... you'll see what I mean in the plunker :) I'm also using `ui-sref` instead of the `ng-click`... using ui-router to its fullest potential

Comment: @AHAY that's what I did but instead of putting the `ui-view`s inside of my html, I've put them in the `views` state template, why didn't it work? I Expect it to be there because it's nested views of this state and not every other state.

Comment: @Jorayen https://plnkr.co/edit/o5zEyhp3ppbFZZtc4oM9?p=preview figured it out! You have to have a blank "view" in your view object within your state. Also needed the `view@state` syntax so Angular knows where to map the states. If you don't mind, I put your template text within a file to make it easier to read.